# Catching Compiler Error in 'createComponent'

Tags: angular, exception

I'm not able to catch any error raised by the `createComponent`-method of [viewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent) (using angular7):

```
try {
    componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
} catch(e) {
    console.log("e", e);
}
```

The error is raised nevertheless and the `catch` block is never executed.

I'm quite sure `createComponent` does not return a promise or anything similar.

My use case: I want to handle errors raised by, for example, unknown variables in the template of the component. Everything works fine if there are no errors, but I have to deal with templates created by users... ;)

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**
Stacktrace (The template contains `{{ foo.bar }}` where `foo` is undefined):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (class_1.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:20458)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19833)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:20011)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19834)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:20032)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19829)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069) undefined
```

Info: I tried uncommenting the specific line and the error disappeared.

Comment: Are you certain that it's `createComponent` that has the error? Perhaps it is part of the Angular lifecycle and in source code that isn't executed in a call stack that includes your code here. Sometimes it can be helpful to inspect the stack trace of any (uncaught) errors.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I updated the question. I tried uncommenting the line and no exception was raised (of course the component was also not created/inserted) so I'm certain the line is causing the error. Does the stacktrace help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error creating your component, which is why you are unable to catch this error where you have added your `try/catch`. It is only after it enters the Angular lifecycle that it starts experiencing issues.

Specifically, it is attempting to access `.bar` of `undefined`. Instead, you could either add a `null` check in your template, or simply use `?`:

```
{{ foo?.bar }}
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no possibility to catch the error in a template?
I know about the '?' option, but thats not related to this case since I'm using templates provided by users which of course can make mistakes.